# How to renew session in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, couchapp, couchrest

I am using COUCHDB built in Session API in my application. I now want to renew the session as every user logs in, also i do not want to give a long expiry time to the session.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question.  It doesn't make sense that you want to "**renew** the session as every user logs in".

The whole idea of a session is that it's a per-user-login session.  Each user who logs in should trigger a `POST /_session` request to your CouchDB server, that will respond with an `AuthSession` cookie which is then what you send back in subsequent requests and that's your session cookie.

The next user who logs in should generate another `POST /_session` which will create a new session cookie for that user.  So there's no renewal as every user logs in.

Now, the expiry on the session is set by the `timeout` setting in the `[couch_httpd_auth]` and defaults to 10 minutes.  If you want it shorter than that then adjust that setting in your `local.ini`

So, finally, if you ever want to explicitly remove the session, eg. from a "logout" button, then you do that by sending a `DELETE /_session` request.

Comment: Lets consider i have 1 day as timeout value in couchdb. i login today at 5 pm and 8pm, here, when will be my AuthSession cookie get expired. 4.59pm or 7.59pm tomorrow.

Comment: It will expire at 5pm the next day.

Comment: But i want to expire on 8.00pm next day. i.e whenever the user logs in, the last time they logged in should be considered for session expiry.  or is there any way that i can renew the AuthSession cookie whenever they logs in?

Comment: As I say in my answer, `POST` to `/_session` to get a new (ie. renew) the auth session.

Comment: @smathy But `DELETE /_session` seems cannot revoke the AuthSession that fetched on my side? Why. [it was asked before](http://grokbase.com/t/couchdb/dev/112pa6tb2d/jira-created-couchdb-1073-delete-session-doesnt-delete-the-session-client-can-still-get-user-information-using-get-session-and-with-the-session-cookie-retrieved), but haven't got an answer.